# Project file changes are not reflecting in laravel 9 project

Tags: php, laravel

I created a project in laravel 9, but if i want to change something in the project file its not working. Even cache was cleared. What is the solution for that?.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: something like what? add more explain please

Comment: if i create a new file, its not working.If i do any changes in existing blade file its reflecting.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new project? Does your device suffer from problems with the operating system or hardware components?

Comment: So editing existing views works but creating a new view doesn't?
Are you setting up routes etc. to see the view on frontend?

Comment: yes i set up routes and everything. I cleared a view cache also. But it's not reflecting project. Is that any permission is needed for a project.

Comment: Do you definitley have a view called try.blade.php?

Comment: "Even cache was cleared" ... what cache? ... sounds like your routes are cached `php artisan route:clear`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are caching route. Try clearing route cache:

```
php artisan route:clear
```